# Drupal 8 Creating a module

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

How to create a simple module in **drupal8** which appends a small JS code ( like google analytics ) in specific the pages.

Most likely with admin setting to select specific page option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `mymodule.libraries.yml` in your module.

```
mymodule.base:
  version: 1.0.0
  js:
    js/your-javascript.js: {}
```

Then us [hook_page_attachments](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.0.x)

```
function photography_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  // Check the request URI or Path to decide if you want to show the library
  //
  // You may use:
  // 1. \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()
  // 2. \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
  //
  $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule.base';
}
```